# Can't get video to play in Firefox

Tags: firefox, mediaelement.js

Using mediaElements.js, my video and audio test work fine in Safari/Chrome on the Mac but not in Firefox (14.0.1). See:
http://global-arts.4pixels.co.uk/global-arts-kingston/events-detail-mediaElement.html All the controls load and when you hit play it looks like it's loading, but then that stops and nothing plays.

To see if my .ogv and .webm files work I have a version of the page without MediaElement.js which is here:
http://global-arts.4pixels.co.uk/global-arts-kingston/events-detail.html and it loads OK, though in Firefox it takes a while to load. My .htaccess file has all the correct filetypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tested with video.js and still finding it didn't work in Firefox, I found it worked locally. Solution was to re-order the stack in .htaccess to have .webm first:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg  .ogv
AddType video/mp4  .mp4
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
```

Only took a weekend to find the problem :-S